# Calling Internet Explorer from command line with bookmark

Tags: command-line, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I understand for calling Internet Explorer from command line is `iexplore.exe`

And for opening a site would be `iexplore.exe http://superuser.com`

If I have created a bookmark for site `http://superuser.com` as `super`, how can I use the bookmark as a switch key along with `iexplore.exe`?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Have you tried just passing it as an argument? IE bookmarks are stored in `C:\Users\<username>\Favorites`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways I can find to do things like that, any way a person wanted.

In the IE9 **file** menu you can **send** a URL to the desktop.
It lands around C:\Users\USERSNAME\Desktop
That icon item called **Super User**, can then be renamed and launched from its icon into the default browser.

I can also go to the CMDprompt and put **"C:\Users\USERSNAME\Desktop\Super User.url"** (with the quotes because of the space) in  and it will also open to the default browser.

If you change your default browser, be it chrome IE firefox or whatever, the URL item will open to the default browser (or program associated to URL).

If you are using "favorites" which are similar "URL" files , IE favorites are stored in   C:\Users\USERSNAME\Favorites\Links
AKA Users -> USERSNAME -> favorites -> Favorites bar.
These shortcuts can be moved around wherever you want, and will fire up the default browser, from the shortcut. They also can be opened via the CMDprompt as shown above.

Depending on the system, getting the favorites path correct might be a bit trickey, use copy/paste methods to aquire the path out of the address bar of the explorer window.

---

If you want to be Sure that Only IE opens that URL item, and you have another browser for default then you would :
Create a shortcut for the IExplore.exe , Which can be found in the Program Files -> Internet Explorer folder
Move that shortcut to wherever you want, name it whatever you want, and Add the URL address as a parameter (as shown below).

In the **properties** for the Internet explorer shortcut icon, go to the **Shortcut** tab and in the **Target** you should see **"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"**  all we have to do is add the URL location in there so it looks like

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://superuser.com"
```

Now you will have a Shortcut icon thing, that will only open IE, and will pass the desired URL as a parameter.

---

In the CMDprompt now you could put in the same whole paths and parameter

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://superuser.com"
```

Or you can actually launch a renamed shortcut itself from the CMDprompt. (as made above) just use the whole path to the shortcut item , or have the shortcut within the systems defined %path%.

> C:\Myshorts\superIE

---

Notes:  Where it says "USERSNAME", you must put in the correct user name, if you do not it will not work.
Use Quotes around each seperate item when there are spaces in the path or the file name.

There are 7 ways to do it, so if you did not see one you like, we can do more.